# Navigation Page Title

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am navigating from one page to another with

`Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new xyzpage()));`

and set the

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

property. I am not able to show the title in the navigation bar.

Comment: You are setting HasNavigationBar to FALSE. Why should you be able to see the title?

Comment: Navigation.PushAsync(new XYZPage());
and Title = "ABC" in constructor of XYZPage() worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all setup the NavigationPage on App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

and every time where you want to navigate to another page add

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new YourPage(),true);
```

If you want to add the Title on the Navigation bar add on the navigated page the following line after Initialize

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
```

and final set the Title

```
Title = "My Page Title";
```

Comment: Navigation.PushAsync(new XYZPage());
and Title = "ABC" in constructor of XYZPage() worked for me. Thanks